# Addition operation of objects in array

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsarray

```
NSArray *discountValues=[AddInvoiceArray valueForKey:@"discount"];

NSLog(@"discount total %@",discountValues);

Console
(
    "420.00",
    "22500.00",
    "4209.00",
    "9800.00"
)
```

I want to add this numbers without for loop.

Comment: can you use enumeration block....  if yes then tell. i will paste the code

Comment: Please clarify: you want to add these numbers using a syntactical construct other than a for loop (for some reason)?  Or you want to do it in a way that is less than O(n)?

Comment: You just need `NSNumber *sum = [discountValues valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"];`

Comment: @Nirav : I got your answer from searching, But where  I mention the key "discount" on it.

Comment: after this line `NSArray *discountValues=[AddInvoiceArray valueForKey:@"discount"];`, use , `NSNumber *sum = [discountValues valueForKeyPath:@"@sum.self"]`

Comment: @Lenin If you directly want sum from the AddInvoiceArray then write like this `NSNumber *sum = [AddInvoiceArray valueForKeyPath:@"@sum. discount"];`

Comment: It works, Thanks guys.